# Uniform boundedness in $L^p$ norm

Tags: integration, lp-spaces

Given a Banach space $X$ and a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset L^p([0,T];X)$ such that 
$$
\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \Vert f_n \Vert_{L^p([0,T];X)} <+\infty
$$
Can we say  that 
$$
\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \Vert f_n(t) \Vert_X <+\infty
$$
for some (or every) $t\in [0,T]$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it true when $X=\mathbb R?$

Comment: I don't know, have you a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider $1^{1/p}\chi_{[0,1]}, 2^{1/p}\chi_{[0,1/2]}, 2^{1/p}\chi_{[1/2,1]},3^{1/p}\chi_{[0,1/3]},3^{1/p}\chi_{[1/3,2/3]},3^{1/p}\chi_{[2/3,1]}, \dots$